# Binding input number with text in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to bind inputs of type 'number' with a different models which are strings. I've managed to bind them using a directive like:

```
app.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        priority:999999,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            //Check del tipo input
            if (attrs.type.toLowerCase() !== 'number') 
            {
                return;
            } 
            //Paso a numero el valor a colocar
            ctrl.$formatters.push(function (value) 
            {
                return value ? parseFloat(value) : null;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And the HTML is like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="scopeValue" />
```

Up to here, there is no problem with binding. But, when I write a ng-repeat and ng-switch combined this directive is not executed. Sample code:

```
<div ng-repeat="attribute in attributes" ng-switch on="attribute.type">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">{{attribute.label}}</span>
    <input class="form-control" ng-switch-when="text" ng-model="attribute.value" type="text" name="{{attribute.label}}" value="{{attribute.value}}">                                   
    <input class="form-control" ng-switch-when="number" ng-model="attribute.value" type="number" name="{{attribute.label}}" value="{{attribute.value}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the directive link code is never thrown and the inputs with number are never completed. As far as I know, the directive checks all the inputs and has the ngModel dependence. Why is it never executed?

Comment: Interesting question. Far as I know ng-switch acts like ng-if and there arise issues with binding in this context. But can you put together a plunker? Here is a template to get you started: http://plnkr.co/edit/WprgipAdFBtxDKM6jogo?p=info (you just need to fork it)

Comment: `name` attribute for the input element cannot be dynamic for the validations to work.

Comment: I've taken out the 'name' attribute but the problem persists.